# Get Role Label instead of Machine Name

Tags: views, 8, theming

I want to know how to show role label in twig view.

I have this

```
{% set roles = user.getroles(TRUE) %}
{{ dump(roles) }}
```

It's giving me my role, but instead of showing **"Directeur (CR)"**, it's showing **"directeur_cr_"** (the machine name or database value).

How can I display "Directeur (CR)"?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
function MYMODULE_field_template_preprocess_default_variables_alter(&$variables) {
  $variables['user_roles'] = user_role_names();
}
```

and in .twig file you can use as `{{user_roles['ROLE_NAME']}}`

Comment: This is in my theme, is this going to work with changing MYMODULE to theme  ?

Comment: Add this in your .module file anywhere in your custom code. It won't work in the theme file.

Comment: How will this give the template the roles the viewed user has?

Comment: This will nor give roles of the current user. `user_roles` will all roles with `id => label`. So, we have to pass the `role id` in `user_roles` to get the label.